# Uploading a File via SCP with Maven fails

Tags: maven-2, upload, scp, wagon

I try to upload an ear created by maven to an application server using scp.

When I tried to run

```
mvn wagon:upload-single
```

But I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:upload-single (default-cli) on project de.volkswagen.dps.ear: Unable to create a Wagon instance for null: url can not be null -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:upload-single (default-cli) on project de.volkswagen.dps.ear: Unable to create a Wagon instance for null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:585)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:247)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:427)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to create a Wagon instance for null
    at org.codehaus.mojo.wagon.AbstractWagonMojo.createWagon(AbstractWagonMojo.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.wagon.AbstractSingleWagonMojo.execute(AbstractSingleWagonMojo.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:577)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: url can not be null
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.repository.Repository.(Repository.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.wagon.shared.WagonUtils.createWagon(WagonUtils.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.wagon.AbstractWagonMojo.createWagon(AbstractWagonMojo.java:79)
    ... 17 more
```

I tried to add this to the pom, but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

I added the following to the pom.xml:

```
...
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>upload-ear</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>upload</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.ear</fromFile> 
                        <url>scp://servername/</url>
                        <toDir>.</toDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
....
```

Can anybody explain how I can make this work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your current configuration follows the example given in the [Usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html) page and is correct. However, in this example the `configuration` element is declared inside an `execution` and thus only applies to **this** particular `execution`.

So when you call `mvn wagon:upload-single` on the command line, the `configuration` isn't "used" and there is indeed no `url` parameter configured.

If you want to call the plugin from the command line, either pass the parameters on the command line using `-Durl=foo` and so on or add a "global" `configuration` element:

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>  

  <plugins>   
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
      <configuration>
        <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.ear</fromFile> 
        <url>scp://servername/</url>
        <toDir>.</toDir>
      </configuration>
      ...
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

Comment: The <toDir> element in the configuration is not considered in wagon:upload-single. You can specify the targetDir in the <url> itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command to run the plugin using the configuration on your `pom.xml`:

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:upload@upload-ear
```