# How deploy maven3 artifact to remote server using scp

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins, scp

I want to have my own maven repository for artifacts created by myself but I have a problem trying to make a deploy of maven 3 artifact to a custom server. To explain this better I'm going to give some information:

- I'm using Maven 3
- I'm using Eclipse Keppler
- I'm using Jenkins
- The remote server is running Ubuntu Server 11.04
- Jenkins is running on the Ubuntu server
- My local machine is running Windows XP

My first attempt was with my machine. I run Maven in Eclipse to make the deploy, and everything works fine. I add the following to my projects pom

```
    <build>
           ...
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
          ...
      </build>

...

<distributionManagement>
      <repository>
          <id>my server id</id>
          <name>my repository name</name>
          <url>scpexe://my server//path/to/my/repository</url>
      </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

And in my settings.xml I add

```
<servers>  
      <server>  
          <id>my server id</id>  
         <username>server username</username>   
         <password>server password</password> 

         <configuration>
             <sshExecutable>plink</sshExecutable>
             <scpExecutable>pscp</scpExecutable>
         </configuration>  

     </server>  
 </servers>
```

So in my local machine it works, but I need to get this work using Jenkins. I modified the Jenkins settings.xml, because it runs on Linux, so doesn't need sshExecutable. The Jenkins settings.xml looks like

```
<servers>  
      <server>  
          <id>my server id</id>  
         <username>server username</username>   
         <password>server password</password> 

     </server>  
 </servers>
```

Then I modified the pom.xml to execute just scp and not scpexe

```
<distributionManagement>
      <repository>
          <id>my server id</id>
          <name>my repository name</name>
          <url>scp://my server//path/to/my/repository</url>
      </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

But according to this page https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes maven 3 does not support scp. I run it any way and I got the following error message from Jenkins log

```
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project myproject: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository my_repository (scp://my server//path/to/my/repository) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
cause : Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository my_repository (scp://my server//path/to/my/repository) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
Stack trace :
```

If I use scpexe instead of scp I got another error message

```
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project pruebanueva: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact {$groupId}:{$artifactId}:{$package}:{$version} from/to my_repository (scpexe://my server//path/to/my/repository): Error executing command for transfer
cause : Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact {$groupId}:{$artifactId}:{$package}:{$version} from/to my_repository (scpexe://my server//path/to/my/repository): Error executing command for transfer
Stack trace :
```

The only way I could make deploy, was doing it in two steps

1. Configuring Jenkins to make just the install goal
2. Running the following command from command line

> mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=$groupId -DartifactId=$artifactId
>   -Dversion=$version  -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=path/to/file.jar -Durl=scp://my server//path/to/my/repository -DrepositoryId=my repository id

I tried many things, including writing that command into Jenkins goal, but everytime I use the scp command in Jenkins the build fails.

Any idea of how to solve this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I am interested to see if there's any real Maven solutions to this. I have always fixed this using the Maven Antrun plugin as follows:

```
<profile>
  <id>deploy</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>deployment.server</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <echo>deploying to server: ${deployment.server}</echo>
                <taskdef classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp" name="scp" />
                <scp file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.war" password="${deployment.password}" todir="${deployment.userName}@${deployment.server}:" trust="true" verbose="true" />
                <!-- <sshexec command="echo unity | sudo -S cp ${project.build.finalName}.jar $( if [ -e /station ]; then echo /station/lib; else echo /opt/pkg-station*/webapps/station*/WEB-INF/lib; fi )" host="${targetStation}" password="unity" trust="true" username="wps"></sshexec> -->
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.25</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

A few notes on this: I activate this profile with a combination of running to the `deploy` phase, and providing a `deployment.server` setting. For my convenience then, I add the corresponding settings to my `settings.xml` so that I don't have to provide these all on the command-line every time:

```
<profile>
    <id>alwaysActiveProfile</id>
    <properties>
        <deployment.server>10.10.10.10</deployment.server>
        <deployment.userName>userName<deployment.userName>
        <deployment.password>password</deployment.password>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

I `skip` the actual `deploy` goal because it will be executed when I run to the `deploy` phase, which I don't want.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not working for me. Where should I put that big "profile"? in my pom.xml? if the answer is yes, where in my pom.xml? inside build tags or another location?. Thanks!!!

Comment: The first (large) fragment goes into your POM file. It's a `profile`, which sits in the POM file XML structure as follows: `project.profiles.profile`. The second fragment goes in your `settings.xml`. You may find this file in the `conf` folder of your Maven installation. There is examples inside the standard `settings.xml` to show you where to put it.

Comment: When I run it I got the following error `Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter`

Comment: It seems that the normal `deploy` goal is executed, which means that `skip` is ignored, which indicates that the profile (`id`=`deploy`) is ignored. That profile should be activated by having any value for `deployment.server`, so the settings may not be right in `settings.xml`. As a test, could you try something like `-Ddeployment.server=10.10.10.10` on the command-line instead to see if at least the profile in the POM is picked up?

Comment: In that case I got the following error message `message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) on project myproject: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run failed...`

Comment: I was at least expecting it to fail for not having user name and password set. Is that collaborated in the rest of the error message? In all, it seems that your first problem is in `settings.xml`. Are you sure the `profile` there is not commented out. There's `<!--` commenting `-->` all over the place in that file.

Comment: I've checked and profile tags are not commented. And the previous error message said something about `Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.7 ()`

Comment: I think <scp file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.war"../> is better to be <scp file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war"../> since the latter also includes the project version.

Comment: I build this particular web application as `${project.artifactId}.war` and then upload it as such. That way I always have the same file name when deployed, which is just, well, convenient. I can see how you would do something different.

Answer (score 0):

The Verhagen's answer is correct but a more pure maven solution is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3303525/1881318

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I already fixed  this by using Archiva because maven 3 doesn't allow scp

Comment: I am not sure how maven would not allow scp. That being said I do have issues making scp to work with a private key instead of a password. See [my question on scp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27538847/744133).