# How to deploy over SCP with private key using Maven

Tags: xml, maven, deployment, scp

Using Maven on windows, transfer over SCP, using a private key.
It seems to be a very simple and documented process. But it didn't work for me.

In the settings.xml

```
<server>
  <id>myserver</id>
  <username>me</username>
  <privateKey>C:/data/home/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
</server>
```

In the pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>myserver</id>
    <url>scp://myserver.domain.com/~me/deploy</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
<build>
  <extensions>
    <!-- Enabling the use of FTP -->
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
       <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
       <version>2.8</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
</build>
```

The expectation is, it should not come to ask me for a password to login. Also note that I do not want to use an external command to make it work uniformly across platforms. However ...

```
--- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ sparksample ---
Downloading: scp://myserver.domain.com/~me/deploy/com/domain/myproject/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 
The authenticity of host 'myserver.domain.com' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 01:01:01:01:01:01:01:01:01:01:01:01:01:01:01:ff.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting? (yes/no): yes
: Password for me@myserver.domain.com:
```

Not only asks it me for a password, it also forces me every time to accept the hostkey.
It did however pickup the settings.xml file, as it is using the correct username to connect.

So how do I avoid it to ask me the password, and use the provided private key? Note that I was able to do this successfully with an ant scp task, using the exact same private key file.

Comment: have you tried to add an empty <passphrase></passphrase> into the settings.xml? Does executing the goal with -X add more information why this fails? The used ssh client might use a different key format. Is it created with openssh?

Comment: Not remembering the exact scenario, here is one possible cause: permissions of following: ~, ~/.ssh, ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote machine. Some sshd implementations will not allow to login if we leave the possibility of tampering with any of those files/directories. If source is unix, ~/.ssh/rsa_id should be suffuciently protected from r/w.

Comment: How does the URL have to look like actually? ^^ First part should be the url to the server and the second part the actual path on the file system, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Read/Write Privileges should be set correctly

```bash
# Current directory should not be writable by others (and preferably not by group either):
chmod o-w ~

chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Only in case id_rsa.pub exists (644 also ok):
chmod 640 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
chmod 640 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

## Ownership should be set correctly

Set to current user and default group. By omitting the group
after the colon, you make sure the group is reset to the default
for that user.

```bash
chown ${USER}: ~
chown -R ${USER}: ~/.ssh
```